# Prove that the serie $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n + a)}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was trying to solve this problem but i got stucked. I use the Radio Test to compute the convergence interval, but it doesnt works in this case, i need help...

1. Prove that the serie $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n + a)}$ converges
2. Calculate the sum of the serie

Comment: Why is this downvoted? She is a new contributor and even told us what she had unsuccessfully tried to solve this.

Comment: I assume you intend $a\ge0$ (although any $a>-1$ works).

Comment: Is $a$ constrained to be an integer? Or can it be any real number?

Comment: Sorry, i am new in the community. $a$  >  0

Comment: No worries! The answers do show that the series does converge, but I know for a fact that you cannot calculate the sum of the series for any old $a$. That is only possible if $a$ is a non-negative integer, and it can be done via telescoping series. (It is possible for some other values, but I'm guessing that is beyond your class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Let $$u_n=\frac{1}{n(n+a)}$$
and
$$v_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

As you know
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$$

$$\implies \frac{u_n}{v_n}\le 2 \text{ for great enough }  n$$

$$\implies 0< u_n\le 2v_n$$
but $$\sum v_n \text{ converges}$$
thus
$$\sum u_n \text{ converges}$$

For the sum, observe that

$$au_n = \frac 1n - \frac{1}{n+a}$$

Comment: Last two lines of your solution does not make a sense to me unless $a$ is a positive integer. For the second part of OP one has go through some special functions and constants.

Comment: @Bumblebee $ a$ is supposed to be $>-1$. If not, the series is not defined.

Comment: @Bumblebee The series defined by the OP starts from $n=1$.

Comment: I see that. My point is, what if $a=\pi$ (for example). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization) for the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is a positive integer, it is possible to calculate the sum of the series.

Note that by [partial fraction decomposition](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm)
$$
\frac1{n(n+a)} = \frac1a\left( \frac1n - \frac1{n+a} \right).
$$
So your sum becomes
$$
\frac1a\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac1n - \frac1{n+a} \right).
$$

Now, if $a$ is a positive integer, we will have a telescoping series. Let's take $a=2$ for example:
$$
\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac1n - \frac1{n+2} \right)
$$
$$
\frac12\left[\left(\frac11-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac14\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac15\right)+\left(\frac14-\frac16\right)+\cdots\right]
$$
Notice how in the first term we subtract $1/3$, but in the third term we add $1/3$. Those $1/3$'s will cancel out. Likewise, the $-1/4$ in the second term is cancelled by the $1/4$ in the fourth term. In fact, we can see that every term after the first two are completely canceled out, as the positive fraction is canceled with the negative fraction of the term 2 before it, and the negative fraction is canceled with the positive fraction of the term 2 after it. Only the first two positive fractions will remain.

So, for $a=2$, the sum is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac12\left(\frac11+\frac12\right)\\
=&\frac34.
\end{align}
$$

We can repeat this process for any positive integer $a$, and we will find that the sum is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1a\left(\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1a\right)\\
=&\frac1a\sum_{n=1}^a\frac1n.
\end{align}
$$

So, it turns out that if $a$ is an integer, we can turn the infinite sum into a finite sum, and easily compute the result.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer help me a lot to understand the problem. I'm very thankfull with you

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $a$ could be any number.
$$\frac{1}{n(n + a)}=\frac 1 a\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n + a} \right)$$
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{n(n + a)}=\frac 1 a\left(H_p+H_a-H_{a+p}\right)$$ Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers, then
$$S_p=\frac{H_a}{a}-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{a+1}{2 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ So $S_p$ converges as long as $\frac{H_a}{a}$ exists.

This excludes all negative integer values of $a$. For any other case, rational, irrational, complex value of $a$, we whall have
$$\lim_{p\to \infty} \, S_p=\frac{H_a}{a}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the comparison test: your series is at least $0$ but at most$$1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1n\right)=2,$$by telescoping.

Answer (score 0):

Compare to integral
$$
\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^2} 
$$